# Simple POST request working like a GET request and timing out

Tags: node.js, express, forms, http-post

I created a simple POST request form to submit an email, but every time I run it, it acts like a GET request that fails.

I tried testing it in postman, but I get a message saying "Could not get any response". The form is incredibly basic, but I can't find anything on the web describing my problem and solution that works.

I've tried this on my local server, on a Heroku server and a Godaddy shared hosting server, all behaved the same.

I've tried adding unnecessary slashes, changing the URl completely, and taking out everything but a console.log.

```
app.post('/sendEmail', (req, res) => {
    console.log('post test');
});
```

```
<form method="POST" action="/sendEmail">
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
      <hr id="contact-page-hr">
      <h4>I am here to serve YOU. Please send your questions my way.</h4>

      <h6 id="contact-name-label"><span><input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Name" value="" id="contact-name-input" required></span></h6>

      <h6 id="contact-email-label"><span><input type="email" name="email" placeholder=" Email" id="contact-email-input" required></span></h6>

      <h6 id="contact-message-label"></h6>
      <textarea name="message" id="contact-message-input" placeholder=" What's on your mind?"></textarea>
      <h6 class="sub-heading">(I usually reply within 48 hours)</h6>
      <button type="submit" class="send-button" id="contact-page-send">Send</button>
    </form>
```

I expect the page to stay put, but instead it says:

"safari can't open the page 'localhost:5000/sendEmail/' because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection...

It's essentially acting like a GET request

Comment: What do you do with the request when received?

Comment: Your request handler does not send any response.  Thus, the browser or server will just eventually time out the connection waiting for a response.  You need to `res.send()` something from the request handler.  The page will stay put if you send the POST request with an Ajax call, but not if you do a form submission.  A form submission expects a new HTML page or a 302 redirect as its response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request handler does not send any response.  Thus, the browser or server will just eventually time out the connection waiting for a response.

An HTTP request expects a response of some kind.  You need to `res.send()` or `res.redirect()` something from the request handler.

The page will stay put only if you send the POST request with an Ajax call, but not if you do a non-Javascript form submission.  A browser form submission expects a new HTML page or something like a 302 redirect as its response and both client and server are waiting for your code to send that until one of them eventually times out and closes the connection in error.

Comment: I had a knowledge gap with the requirement to reload the page/render something as a response. AJAX is the key to getting the behavior I want, I had heard of it, but hadn't looked into it until now. Thank you!